# How to Update a Data Model based on a set of values

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, iterable

The scenario is to update Data models inside a list based on a `Set` of integer values.

For example an ArrayList having :

```
Student {
    name: "abc",
    id: 1,
    hasPassed: false
}...
```

Now I have a set of Integers which basically has 
student IDs inside it {1, 2, ...} denoting student IDs of passed students.

I get hold of the arrayList of `Student` inside an `onNext` Method of my `observer`.

How to update the `hasPassed` field of student object(s) based on the student IDs I get from the integer `Set` ? I am trying to use RxJava2 to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can start by iterating over the students set by using flatmapIterable() oberator which will emit items one by one to deal with, then you can use flatmap() to apply an operation on the emitted item, finally if you want your list back use toList() operator .. it may looks like something like

```
Observable.fromIterable(studentList) //emit items one by one
    .flatMap(studentItem -> { //make an operation on item
      if (ids.contains(studentItem.getId())) {
        studentItem.setHasPassed(true);
      }
      return Observable.just(studentItem); //emit item 
    })
    .toList() //get all items on a list
    .subscribe(finalList->{ 
         //handle the result
        }, throwable -> {
         //handlle error
    });
```

Comment: cool! not sure why but I am getting a "missing return statement" error near the `});` am I missing something here?

Comment: still the same error at `}).toList().subscribe(` for a missing return statement inside `})`

Comment: @beerBear I forgot to told you that you must subscribe your observable to an observer or the stream will never be executed, please not that this is a pseudo cod like. if you're not familiar with lamda, you can try use Android studio auto complete and take care of the types in operators anonymous methods.

Comment: @beerBear well, I just wrote my code on Android studio and there is no error, I will update the answer for the second time :)

Comment: I was looking out for `fromIterable()`. Neat! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Even though Mohamed's answer is acceptable, there is no need for using `flatMap`, because you don't want to convert one item into a stream of items, but just convert the item into another item. So a better solution would be to use `map` operator:

```
Observable.fromIterable(list)
          .map(student -> {
              if (getPassedIds().contains(student.getId())) {
                  return new Student(student.getId(), student.getName(), true);
               } else {
                  return student;
               }
           })
          .toList()
          .subscribe(students -> students.forEach(student -> logd(student.toString())),
                     throwable -> { //handle error});
```

In my example I used an immutable class, so you don't have to reuse the same user but you create another user with the same properties, except for the `hasPassed` boolean: immutability has a lot of advantages and it is a good idea to use immutable classes when possible.